# Darktable film rolls — how to remove a film roll from 'collect images'?

Tags: darktable

darktable: I have begun using this app. One question, how are unwanted fill rolls removed from 'collect images'. There are several fill rolls I created from folders that I no longer want to keep in darktable. How can I delete these? I can see nothing!

Comment: @RomeoNinov It's a question about how to use software that organizes and processes photographs. Part of photography is managing the images one has captured, whether that is via storing negatives in a file cabinet or organized digital image files using software.

Answer (score 5):

There is indeed no remove button for film rolls in darktable; according to the program's developers, this is a [feature, not a bug](https://github.com/darktable-org/darktable/issues/2490).

You can remove a film roll, however, by opening the roll, selecting all photos in the roll and clicking 'remove' under 'selected image(s)' in the right-hand toolbar. This will remove those photos from darktable's database but not delete the photos from your file system (if the latter outcome is desired, click 'trash' instead).

Comment: Thanks. That both answers my question and tells me what I need to do.

Comment: Based on the “not a bug” elaboration at the end of the linked page, it’s not a bug in the sense that it isn’t an error of the code’s logic. However, it isn’t a feature either - it’s missing functionality that should be logged as a “feature request”, not a “bug report”. Semantics, perhaps, but at least they’re not against that functionality.